# Get previous item in grid winrt

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="gridGeneralProperties" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="613" Margin="233,5,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="437">
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="General Properties" FontSize="16" Margin="162,10,18,573"/>
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Name" Margin="10,69,298,521" FontSize="14.667"/>
    <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Document.DocumentName}" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="144,59,73,520"/>
    <AppBarButton x:Name="appBarButtonEditName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Label="" Margin="349,39,-12,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Icon="Edit" Height="75"/>
</Grid>
```

Is there a way to access the previous in a grid? In this case, if a user clicks on the AppBarButton, I want to make the previous TextBox editable. In all instances of where the button is clicked, the previous item will be a TextBox.

Comment: What do you mean "the previous in a grid"? In any case, you Mvvm and a binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case - you know which one is previous in your XAML - you can simply name it to access it.

The general solution would be to get the index of the starting element in the `Grid.Children` collection and the previous one will be at index - 1.

MVVM is the way to go though. I'm also not sure why you would need a button to make a `TextBox` editable - just leave it editable always and you save the space.